# User controls for creating certain models

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, crud

I'm new to WPF and I found that creating a custom component for my case would be the best, so please tell me if I'm wrong at first. The purpose of this idea is to reuse it in other scenarios as needed.

The `Model`:

```
public class FooModel
{
    public string Whatever { get; set; }
}
```

The `ViewModel`:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public FooModel Foo { get; set; }

    public ICommand CreateCommand { get; set; } = new AnotherCommandImplementation<FooModel>(model =>
    {
        // model is null! :(
    });
}
```

The `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:FooViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Foo.Whatever}" Height="23" Width="120"/>
        <Button CommandParameter="{Binding Foo}" Command="{Binding CreateCommand}" Width="80" Content="Create"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Why is `Foo` null and how do I fix it?

**UPDATE**

As requested, here's the current DataTemplate technique attempt:

`App.xaml`:

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vms:KeyboardActionViewModel}">
            <ctrs:KeyboardActionControl />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Window:

```
<Window>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vms:ActionExecutorViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Enabled}" Content="Enabled" />
        <UserControl Content="{Binding Action}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ActionExecutorViewModel : ViewModel<ActionExecutor>
{
    private Boolean enabled;
    private ActionViewModel action;

    public ActionExecutorViewModel()
    {
        Action = new KeyboardActionViewModel(); // Test
    }

    public ActionViewModel Action
    {
        get => action;
        set => AssignAndRaiseEventOnPropertyChange(ref action, value);
    }

    public Boolean Enabled
    {
        get => enabled;
        set => AssignAndRaiseEventOnPropertyChange(ref enabled, value);
    }

    public override ActionExecutor BuildModel()
    {
        var executor = new ActionExecutor();

        executor.Action = action.BuildModel();

        return executor;
    }
}
```

`KeyboardActionControl`:

```
<UserControl>
    <Label Background="Aqua">Asadsadsad</Label>
</UserControl>
```

`ActionViewModel` is an abstract class where `KeyboardActionViewModel` inherits from it.

Comment: Because you never set it to anything? What makes you think it *would* hold a value? (Chances are you want it passed in via Dependency Property, fyi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sereja notes, your proximal issue is that `Foo` is null. You never created it, so it's not there. It should probably be instantiated by `FooViewModel`, but it's possible that the creator of FooViewModel should create Foo as well. Without knowing the semantics, I can't be sure. The view should absolutely not be responsible for creating either one.

But there are bad assumptions built into what you're doing. Let's correct those and get you on the right track.

`ViewModelBase` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Examples abound. The view XAML snippets below are intended to be partial: There are bits of UI which are not illustrated, as they shouldn't present any difficulties.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ActionExecutorCollectionViewModel ActionExecutors { /* INPC stuff */ }
        //  ViewModels create their own children. 
        = new ActionExecutorCollectionViewModel();
}

public class ActionExecutorCollectionViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ActionExecutor> Items { /* INPC stuff */ }
    public ActionExecutor NewActionExecutor { /* INPC stuff */ }

    // Create new ActionExecutor and assign to NewActionExecutor 
    public ICommand CreateActionExecutor { /* ... */ }

    // Add NewActionExecutor to Items and set NewActionExecutor to null 
    public ICommand SaveActionExecutor { /* ... */ }
}
```

Write an implicit DataTemplate for each of the above. In MainViewModel's DataTemplate, there's something like this:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ActionExecutors}" />
```

That displays the ActionExecutorsViewModel with its implicit DataTemplate, which contains something like this, among other things:

```
<Button
    Command="{Binding CreateActionExecutor}"
    Content="Create"
    />
<Button
    Command="{Binding SaveActionExecutor}"
    Content="Save"
    />
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding NewActionExecutor}"
    />
```

ActionExecutor needs some kind of crude class factory to create its own Action. You have two action types now. I would advise against going crazy at the moment trying to write a perfect architecture for adding new ones in the future. I would instead suggest giving ActionExecutor a public readonly collection of action type options, probably values from an enum: `public ActionType { Mouse, Keyboard }`, and a `public ActionType ActionType` property. When ActionType changes, create a new action of the new type and assign it to the Action property. ActionType’s setter should call a protected method which does that. There are other, more clever options for this, but the above design is reasonably maintainable and has served well in thousands of production applications.

In ActionExecutor's implicit DataTemplate, you would have a combobox which lets the user select a type of action from the `ActionTypes` collection. Its SelectedItem property is bound to `ActionType`. This is how actions are created.

ActionExecutor's DataTemplate contains something like this:

```
<CheckBox Content="Enabled" IsChecked="{Binding Enabled}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ActionTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding ActionType}" />
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Action}" />
```

1. All viewmodels below MainViewModel are created by their immediate parent viewmodels, **never never never ever by a view**. Think of the viewmodel "tree" as the skeleton or framework of the application. Views just display bits of it as needed. **Viewmodels need to communicate with each other; views don’t**. They just reflect and instigate state changes in their viewmodels. The window can create its viewmodel in its constructor, or in XAML as `<Window.DataContext><local:MainViewModel /></Window.DataContext>`. Either is fine, but doing it in the constructor allows you to call a constructor that has parameters.
2. Thus, with that one exception, a UserControl ***always*** gets its DataContext from context, ***never*** by creating it. This is a practical matter, not ideological: It makes writing and maintaining the application very much easier than the alternative. Many vexing issues are swept out of existence when you follow this rule. It's rare for a UserControl in a well-designed WPF application to define dependency properties. The purpose of a UserControl is to display a viewmodel. Other types of controls will define vast, lavish, glittering assortments of dependency properties. Not UserControls.
3. You can write UserControls and put them in DataTemplates, or just write DataTemplates. I believe that writing UserControls is a good idea. A DataTemplate containing a UserControl looks EXACTLY LIKE THIS:

   ```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ActionExecutor}">
       <local:ActionExecutorUserControl />
   </DataTemplate>
   ```
4. `DataContext="{Binding SomeProperty}"` is essentially always wrong. It’s a “code smell” which indicates that somebody doesn’t understand XAML very well yet.

If some part of the above doesn't make sense to you, I'll be happy to help you fill that gap in your knowledge. If you believe that some part of it conflicts with your requirements, you may very well be mistaken. However, it is your responsibility to fully understand and codify your own requirements, and to communicate those requirements clearly.

## UPDATE

Implicit DataTemplates

An implicit datatemplate is 1) a datatemplate defined as a resource in an accessible ResourceDictionary, with 2) a DataType attribute specifying which one of your classes you want to display with it.

App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ActionExecutorCollectionViewModel}">
        <local:ActionExecutorCollectionUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ActionExecutor}">
        <local:ActionExecutorUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MouseAction}">
        <local:MouseActionUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- And so on and so forth. -->
</Application.Resources>
```

MainWindow.xaml

MainWindow's DataContext is your MainViewModel, which I've partially defined above.

```
<Grid>
    <!-- 
    MainViewModel.ActionExecutors is of type ActionExecutorCollectionViewModel.
    If you defined an implicit datatemplate for that class in some ResourceDictionary 
    that's in scope here (e.g., App.xaml), this UserControl will automatically 
    use that datatemplate. 
    -->
    <UserControl Content="{Binding ActionExecutors}" />
</Grid>
```

ActionExecutorUserControl.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label>Interval</Label>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Interval}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Enabled}">Enabled</CheckBox>

    <!-- 
    If you have implicit datatemplates defined for all your action types,
    the framework will automatically give this UserControl the correct template
    for whatever actual type of action the Action property refers to.

    This is where we begin to see the real value of implicit datatemplates. 
    -->
    <UserControl Content="{Binding Action}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193063/discussion-on-answer-by-ed-plunkett-user-controls-for-creating-certain-models).

Answer (score 0):

There is not constructor that initializes `Foo` with non-default values (which `null` is for reference types). That's the reason. At least, provide such a constructor, or - more WPFic way - create a `DataContext="{Binding Foo}"`; that's probably what you wanted, however your `XAML` is wrong then: you are creating `new` instance all the time rather than consuming the view model's `Foo` instance.

P.S. More than that, for `UserControl`s it is command to expose a `DependencyProperty` to take the underlying model; so it would look like `<UserControl Model="{Binding Foo}" ... />`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although, could you enlighten me a little bit more? the `<UserControl Model=>` is probably what I've been looking for... Please provide a sample. Also, if I set my control to use a certain model and took that button out of the control, how do I retrieve all the bindinds/attributes values from my control on a button click, for example (a button outside the control)?

Comment: @Henri, why don't you go ahead and check appropriate docs? It's a huge topic, can't be covered on the fly. But I've definitely gave you a right perspective.

Comment: I'm asking it here because I couldn't find any examples of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov Please don't suggest binding `DataContext="{Binding Foo}"`. That's very rarely a good idea. FooViewModel should probably be the DataContext of the UserControl in this case, in which case any bindings in the UserControl should be just as they are in the XAML in the question.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, that's why I said to expose a `DependencyProperty`. Like `FooProperty`, you know.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov Neither is a good idea. Please read my answer below.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov Your "FooProperty" is an attempt to reinvent DataContext, but there's no need. DataContext works wonderfully well just as it is. Replacing DataContext with a novel dependency property would require additional kludgey workarounds to reinvent other behavior of DataContext. However, there is no defect in DataContext which needs to be worked around. Replacing it just adds complexity and development/maintenance overhead, for no benefit at all.